Cant login django administrator
why when is_staff = false and is_superuser = true I still can't log in to the django administrator dashboard.
Can I do something custom so that is_superuser can still log in even though is_staff is false?.can anyone help me?

Because the admin requires is_staff is True, usually it also does not make much sense that is_superuser=True and is_staff=False.

Because the admin requires is_staff is True, indeed, in the Django documentation [Django-doc], we read:

If you need to create a user to login with, use the createsuperuser command. By default, logging in to the admin requires that the user has the is_staff attribute set to True.

This is checked in the AdminAuthenticationForm with [GitHub]:

def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
    super().confirm_login_allowed(user)
    if not user.is_staff:
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["invalid_login"],
            code="invalid_login",
            params={"username": self.username_field.verbose_name},
        )

So it checks if the user.is_staff:

Can I do something custom so that is_superuser can still log in even though is_staff is false?

Usually it also does not make much sense that is_superuser=True and is_staff=False, since a superuser is normally one level "higher" than staff.
You could make a customized form and then register that in the admin site:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        **AuthenticationForm.error_messages,
        'invalid_login': _(
            'Please enter the correct %(username)s and password for a staff '
            'account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.'
        ),
    }
    required_css_class = 'required'

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        super().confirm_login_allowed(user)
        if not user.is_superuser:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                code='invalid_login',
                params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
            )


def has_permission(self, request):
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_superuser


admin.site.login_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
admin.site.has_permission = has_permission
Likely it will require altering extra checks.
